# sqlcmd mode from SSMS - setvar assignment to a substitution variable possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm running this from SSMS 2008R2 with SQLCMD Mode enabled.

With the code below:

```
:SETVAR GREETING "HELLO"
:SETVAR SALUTATION $(GREETING)

SELECT '$(GREETING)'
SELECT '$(SALUTATION)'
```

I see the following in the results:

```
HELLO
$(GREETING)
```

I was hoping to see:

```
HELLO
HELLO
```

Is there a way to have a scripting variable in the assignment of another scripting variable?  If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variable substitution in :SETVAR doesn't work, because in this case it's just a token substitution.

You can simulate the behaviour you expect as this:

```
:SETVAR GREETING "HELLO"

DECLARE @salutation VARCHAR(5) = $(GREETING);
SELECT @salutation;
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the opposite if you need to:

```
DECLARE @firstVar VARCHAR(30) = 'theUltimateValue';

:setvar secondValue @firstVar

select $(secondValue) as whatIReallyWant
```

Returns

```
whatIReallyWant
------------------------------
theUltimateValue
```